# Can we find all indecomposale modules over a path algebra?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a finite linear quiver. Let $R$ be a commutative (possibly semisimple) ring. is it a known way to characterize all indecomposable $R{\mathcal Q}$?

Comment: What do you mean by linear quiver? Do you mean Dynkin type A with linear orientation, or only acyclic, or ...?

Comment: If you ask for $Q$ acyclic, this is in general not possible, even if $R$ is a field. If you mean Dynkin type A this should be possible if $R$ is semisimple commutative since a semisimple commutative ring is just a direct product of fields. I would expect dropping commutative doesn't even make a big difference since this should still be Morita equivalent to  $DQ$ where $D$ is a skew-field, so should be very similar to the field case. If $R$ is not necessarily semisimple, this task is in general again impossible (impossible meaning it is a wild problem).